# Alternative to FiraCode for coding purposes

Tags: fonts, ide, ligature

I've looked for improving my coding experience and read blogs about ligatures like [this one](https://practicaltypography.com/ligatures-in-programming-fonts-hell-no.html). While interesting as a concept, all the resources I've found are about [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions). The impression I've got is that it's de facto standard and virtually the only font available for ligaturing in coding context.

The problem is that I find it a bit unpleasant for the eyes. It's tightened up compared to my beloved Consolas. Probably, what's so appealing is the monospace style of it, which doesn't need to collide with the ligatures. I'd like to see an extension to Consolas (or similar) that substitutes all the characters for ligatures only on the arrows, comparers etc.

Is there such a thing or did I google it right, not finding jack?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/somq/consolas-ligaturized/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @RavishaHesh That would be the perfect option. Regrettably, I'm not sure how to install that font. I entered "Consolas ligaturized" in the Visual Studio Code settings but I guess there's no such font installed on my system and the docs at the link you provided are, well... brief. Suggestions?

Comment: It's "Consolas Ligaturized Regular", and also don't forget to turn on editor.fontLigatures setting. I can assure you that it's working perfectly because I just installed it

Comment: I do believe you. However, it doesn't seem to work on my system, despite activating the ligatures (Fira Code is showing when I enter that into the settings). I suspect that I have to install the font you suggested and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Download this file https://github.com/somq/consolas-ligaturized/blob/master/Consolas-FiraCode_v2/Consolasligaturizedv2.ttf?raw=true
2. Double Click on the file and press "Install"(Windows) or "Install Font"(Mac)
3. In your fonts folder it will appear as "Consolas Ligaturized Regular"
   [image]
4. Change the font family in VSCode to "Consolas Ligaturized Regular" if you are using Windows, "Consolas Ligaturized" is sufficent if you are using Mac

Windows

[image]

Mac

[image]

5. Turn on Ligatures
   [image]

Result

[image]

**Update 20/07/01**

Fixed broken link. Thanks [MountainDrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1949542/mountaindrew) for pointing out

Comment: In Windows the font showed up as "Consolas ligaturized v2" and that was what I had to enter in VSCode.

Comment: v3 is out now, the links above are for v2

Answer (score 4):

I recently looked for a change; so I looked around and found some interesting fonts for developers (fonts support ligatures). I just link them:

1. [IOSEVKA](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka)
2. [MONOID](https://larsenwork.com/monoid/?ref=betterwebtype)
3. [HASKLIG](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig?ref=betterwebtype)
4. [JetBrains MONO](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/?ref=betterwebtype)

For more information please refer to each provided link or just simply search for the font name.